# Someone explain Geneva Framework and WIF

Tags: authentication, wif, claims-based-identity, geneva-framework

I am dumb and don't know what these two frameworks provides. I wanted to move to claims based authentication and don't understand what these two frameworks provide to me. Are these two providing the same functionality just named differently or they have a purpose?

Is there a question on SO that will help me getting started with porting existing forms authentication application to "Claims Based Authentication" ?

thank you very very much for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geneva is now called Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS).

It is a Security Token Service (STS) which issues signed tokens containing attributes about a user (name, email etc.)

WIF is the set of classes you include in a ASP.NET application that provides the plumbing to connect to ADFS.

Have a look at:

[A Guide to Claims-Based Identity and Access Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx)

[AD FS 2.0 Content Map](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2735.ad-fs-2-0-content-map.aspx)

[Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) Content Map](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3665.windows-identity-foundation-wif-content-map.aspx)

**Update**

The WIF link above contains a link to [Get Started with Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3487.get-started-with-windows-identity-foundation-wif.aspx) which includes the Identity Training Kit and some "Getting Started" examples.

Comment: +1 perfect answer. I need both now to work. But then do you know any getting started which explains how to port existing ASP.NET Forms Authentication system to ADFS and Claims model